# RE: Process builder condition not satisfying in test class

Tags: unit-test, process-builder, failing-tests

I have written test class where iam inserting the task records and then task status field is updating.

```
Task taskRec1 = new Task();

taskRec1.AES_CNTR__UCID__c  = 'abcd';
taskRec1.ARM_Property__c = accountRec.id;  
taskRec1.WhatId=cselist.id;  
taskRec1.Subject = 'Call';
taskRec1.Status = 'In Progress';
taskRec1.Priority = 'Normal';
taskRec1.Regional__c=false; 
taskList.add(taskRec1); 
insert taskList;

taskRec1.Status = 'Completed';
taskRec1.Completed_By__c = taskRec1.LastModifiedBy.FirstName + '' + taskRec1.LastModifiedBy.LastName;

update taskRec1;
```

at the same time process builder is firing with the condition if task status is completed then update the task
`task.completed_by__c = taskRec1.LastModifiedBy.FirstName + '' + taskRec1.LastModifiedBy.LastName;`

Though I have satisfied the condition in  test class above update taskRec1.
still the test class is not passing.

Comment: Can you share the assertion part as well?

Comment: why is your testmethod setting the value of `Completed_By__c` if the PB's job is to do exactly that?